# Eclipse, Plugin, Java Project, Custom Nature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project

I have written a plugin which is a simple validator for some java classes. (Additional *logic* validation)

I used a custom nature to ommit manual adding of builders to any project.

When i have a project Folder of type "Project" or "Maven" - the Add/Remove [MyNature] button is visible. However for Java-Projects, the ui-contribution is not available...

(and I need to add it to Maven-Projects which also have the nature Java-Project...)

The menucontributions are defined like this:

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.projectConfigure?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="my.namespace.lazyloadingvalidatorplugin.addRemoveLazyLoadingNature"
               label="Remove Lazy Loading Nature"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="selection">
                  <count
                        value="1">
                  </count>
                  <iterate>
                     <and>
                        <instanceof
                              value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                        </instanceof>
                        <test
                              value="my.namespace.lazyloadingvalidatorplugin.lazyLoadingNature"
                              property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature">
                        </test>
                     </and>
                  </iterate>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
         <command
               commandId="my.namespace.lazyloadingvalidatorplugin.addRemoveLazyLoadingNature"
               label="Add Lazy Loading Nature"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="selection">
                  <count
                        value="1">
                  </count>
                  <iterate>
                     <and>
                        <instanceof
                              value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                        </instanceof>
                        <not>
                           <test
                                 value="my.namespace.lazyloadingvalidatorplugin.lazyLoadingNature"
                                 property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature">
                           </test>
                        </not>
                     </and>
                  </iterate>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

I also tried to add the nature to the pom file, using the following entries:

```xml
<additionalProjectnatures>
    <projectnature>
        lazyLoadingNature
    </projectnature>
</additionalProjectnatures>
<buildcommands>
    <buildcommand>
        my.namespace.lazyloadingvalidatorplugin.lazyLoadingBuilder
    </buildcommand>
</buildcommands>
```

no success... any ideas what is wrong?

---

figured out, its the check

```xml
<instanceof
   value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
</instanceof>
```

that fails... Removing this condition leads to simultaneously showing the "Add" and "Remove" button for Jave-Nature-Projects... Well, could live with that - question just *why* and *how* to do it right :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```xml
<adapt
   type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
</adapt>
```

instead of `instanceof`. Objects shown in views are often not actual instances of Projects, Files.... but can be 'adapted' to those objects.